# Speech recognition in Python

Tags: python, speech

I found the speech module and i can get my computer to say the stuff i write. But the problem is when i try out the example code from here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/speech/0.5.1 It gives me an error and can't do it. This is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
response = speech.input("Say something, please.")
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\speech.py", line 162, in input
listener = listenforanything(response)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\speech.py", line 193, in listenforanything
return _startlistening(None, callback)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\speech.py", line 222, in _startlistening
context = _recognizer.CreateRecoContext()
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628x0x5x4.py", line 2648, in CreateRecoContext
ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(10, LCID, 1, (9, 0), (),)
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception raised.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147200905),    None)
```

I really hope someone can help me.

Thanks alot in advance,

Jake

Comment: Have you installed the Microsoft Speech Kit?

Comment: Yeah i have. It should be installed if it is able to say what is written, shouldn't it? Or is it possible that it can do it without even having that kit installed?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the speech module to function properly you must also install pywin32.

Comment: The last line of the traceback shows that the user actually has _pywin32_ installed. The problem most probably lies with not having the _Microsoft Speech Kit_ properly installed.